# npm все устанавливает в одну папку

Tags: npm

Насколько я знаю, при установке пакетов через npm без параметров они должны устанавливаться локально, именно в тот каталог, откуда я и ввожу команду. Однако в моем случае при локальной установке npm устанавливает все в домашний каталог ~/node_modules. Ему не интересно, откуда именно я вводил команду.

В принципе, такое поведение выглядит даже более аккуратным (нет кучи хлама по разным каталогам), но хотелось бы узнать, нормально ли это, или что-то работает не так?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Флаг `-g` точно не добавляли?

Comment: Точно. Сейчас попробовал установить lodash с флагом --save-dev, все равно ставит в домашнюю директорию. Это уже явно ненормально.